# Strange problems with useEffect and useSelector cause infinite loops

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Now I do not understand why the data value obtained by `useSelector` is monitored by `useEffect` and `useState` is used to render the page in a closed loop.

Here's my code：

```js
const data = useSelector((state: DeviceList) => {
  if (state.basicSetting !== null) {
    return state.basicSetting.filter(
      item =>
        item.deviceName.includes('ac') &&
        !item.deviceName.includes('bz'),
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});

const [list, setList] = useState<DeviceDataOne[][]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data !== null) {
    let arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < (data as DeviceDataOne[]).length; i += 4) {
      arr.push((data as DeviceDataOne[]).slice(i, i + 4));
    }
    setList(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)));
  } else {
    setList([]);
  }
}, [data]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('list', list);
}, [list]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('data', data);
}, [data]);
```

My understanding of `useEffect` monitoring should be that when the `data` is changed, he will re-execute the code in `useEffect`. However, I actually found that such writing would lead to infinite re-rendering. Therefore, I can't understand why there is an endless loop.

I tried to comment the middle piece of code

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (data !== null) {
    let arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < (data as DeviceDataOne[]).length; i += 4) {
      arr.push((data as DeviceDataOne[]).slice(i, i + 4));
    }
    setList(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)));
  } else {
    setList([]);
  }
}, [data]);
```

But I don't understand why I can't write it like this or what causes such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding of `useEffect` monitoring should be that when the
> data is changed, he will re-execute the code in `useEffect`.

Your understanding of the `useEffect` hook is correct, but you are not understanding that your `useSelector` hook is potentially returning a new array object reference each time the component renders. In other words, `data` is a new reference that triggers the `useEffect` hook to run. The `useEffect` hook enqueues a `list` state update. When React processes the `list` state update it triggers a component rerender. `data` is selected and computed from the Redux store. Repeat ad nauseam.

You can help break the cycle by using an equality function with the `useSelector` hook. See [Equality Comparisons and Updates](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates).

```js
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

...

const data = useSelector((state: DeviceList) => {
  if (state.basicSetting !== null) {
    return state.basicSetting.filter(
      item =>
        item.deviceName.includes('ac') &&
        !item.deviceName.includes('bz'),
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}, shallowEqual); // <-- shallow equality instead of strict equality
```

Another good solution is to create a memoized selector function from [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), and since you are using Redux-Toolkit, [createSelector](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) is re-exported from Reselect. (*Reselect is maintained by the same Redux/Redux-Toolkit developers*)

It allows you to write the same computed `data` value but it memoizes the result so that if the selected state going *into* the selector hasn't changed, then the selector returns the same previously computed value. In other words, it provides a stable returned `data` value that will only trigger the `useEffect` when state actually updates and the selector computes a new value reference.

However, it is a bit unclear *why* you are selecting state from the store and duplicating it locally into state. This is generally considered a React anti-pattern. You can compute the `list` value directly from the store.

Example:

```js
const list = useSelector((state: DeviceList) => {
  if (state.basicSetting === null) {
    return null;
  }
  
  const data = state.basicSetting.filter(
    item =>
      item.deviceName.includes('ac') &&
      !item.deviceName.includes('bz'),
  ) as DeviceDataOne[];

  const list: DeviceDataOne[] = [];
  while (data.length) {
    list.push(data.splice(0, 4));
  }
  return list;
});

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('list', list);
}, [list]);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mind seems to be imprisoned, thinking that I should classify this data for him and process it without thinking that I could directly process the data in useSelector. This is a simple mistake I made

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding of useEffect monitoring should be that when the data is changed, he will re-execute the code in useEffect.

That's correct, but `data` *is* being changed: the `useSelector` function is returning a new list each time your component is rendered, and in JavaScript, two lists aren't considered equal just because they currently contain the same elements.

The reason your effect is triggering an infinite loop is that it changes the `list` state every time, which triggers a new render, which changes `data`, which triggers the effect again.

Comment: Can I understand that when useState is setState again, view re-rendering is triggered and view re-rendering is triggered to re-execute the data obtained by useSelector and data re-acquisition is monitored by useEffect He performed setState again for such reasons as to cause an infinite loop